# Anime where genetically modified girls fight aliens/sea monsters

Tags: story-identification, anime

They're genetically modified girls that fight aliens/sea monsters but are paired with a guy. They have been modified with the monsters DNA and they go to a university/academy to learn to fight until they graduate and can fight the invaders in their squad. The things that attack are huge with tentacle arms and in one episode the things absorb the girls that are fighting them and turning them into mindless drones.

Comment: When did you see this?

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the tips at ["How to ask a good story-ID question?"](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/85401) -- there are various types things that if you can recall any of them, may help potential answerers. E.g. About what year was the anime from? Can you remember any visual details? Do you know what network, if any, you saw it on? Do you remember any details from its opening or ending theme? Etc.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: This sound like Kantai Collection or Azure Lane when I heard it (only sea monster). But with aliens it just too many.

Answer (score 3):

As per [Anime about half-human girls who fight monsters?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188723/anime-about-half-human-girls-who-fight-monsters), this may be *[Black Bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Bullet)*.

> This anime aired in 2014, and was a one-cours series, lasting 13 episodes. It takes place in a world devastated by the "Gastrea" entities, and the characters who fight the Gastrea are divided into pairs of a "Promoter", who leads their partner in their battles, and an "Initiator", who is a "Cursed Child". The Cursed Children are young women whose bodies were altered by the effects of the Gastrea before they were born. Since the series takes place about ten years after the Gastrea appeared, the Cursed Children are all around ten years old.

Found with a search for `anime girls fight sea monsters`

Answer (score 2):

The name of this anime is [Freezing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezing_(manga)#Anime)

> The series revolves around the invasion of Earth by an interdimensional
>   force called the Nova, and a special military group of genetically
>   engineered young women called Pandoras. Pandoras fight alongside their
>   male partners known as Limiters, who are created to combat the Nova.
>   The story centers around Kazuya Aoi, a Limiter whose late sister was a
>   Pandora, and Satellizer el Bridget, a Pandora with a cold personality
>   who is known as the "Untouchable Queen" due to her intense aphephobia.
>   Both are enrolled at West Genetics Academy, which is a training school
>   for Pandoras and Limiters.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: And is this the same one as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezing_(manga)?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please check [How to write a good story-ID answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9445/31394) - essentially, it should be useful to both the asker and the site, explaining what anime you're referring to and how it matches the description given in the question.