# Webcomic involving an armless girl fighting sea monsters

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I was reminded of this while researching [Anime where genetically modified girls fight aliens/sea monsters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/229620/anime-where-genetically-modified-girls-fight-aliens-sea-monsters). It was a webcomic that starred a buxom girl without arms (but with robotic floating [waldos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_manipulator)) who acted as something like a corporate-sponsored superheroine, fighting off creatures that came in by the sea. As the comic progressed, it was revealed first that the heroine's lack of arms was the result of her father trying to give her powers (basically, through some combination of chemicals and radiation, she wound up with the birth defect on non-developed limbs) and that the "monsters" are actually benign, carrying cargo for other companies, with her father's company seizing what they were carrying.

I remember there being sort of a timeskip, then she was kind of operating on her own, eventually befriending a girl with some sort of eldritch transformation resulting in eyes and mouths forming all over her body. I want to say there was some sort of romantic subplot going on there. And I think, not long after that, the webcomic was discontinued and then the creator took the site down. The artwork was pretty good, cartoony but well-drawn. A lot of lightly or spandex clad women with large breasts, as one often sees in such comics, occasional upper-body nudity. I think the creator had another webcomic strip they were better known for which was more adult.

And... in the process of pulling more details, I think I've found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the process of doing some searches for variations of monsters, superheroines, and a lack of arms, `webcomic "no arms"` turned up [a review](https://webcomicoverlook.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/wco237-redd/) of *[Redd](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Webcomic/Redd)*.

Review:

> That’s right, readers. Redd is a superhero with no arms and also no clothes. Because while she may not have been born with limbs, at least she was born with the things that did matter: her jugs and her legs. Amirite, fellas? You know what I’m talking about. She does have two red robot hands, though, which float around her basically in around the same position if she had arms. It’s sort of a phantom limb thing, like that Venture Bros. character of the same name.
>
> Which brings to mind a question: if you were a scientist developing these cool new appendages for Redd, why wouldn’t you give her actual arms? Throughout the comic, I was sorta wondering if maybe there were complications because Redd wasn’t born with arms. Like, she would really know how to use limbs if she’d lived all hear life without them. Maybe the floating robo-hands were easier to use? But, wait, later we see her in disguise deploying an arrangement of six workable arms. So… it is possible for Redd to not look so dang weird, flying around in the sky with no arms nor care in the world.
>
> Redd works for some sort of scientific organization that provides her upgrades, knick-knacks, and other sorts of technical doo-dads. They provide, for example, her skintight outfit, which can withstand cannon fire. Now I know what you’re saying. “Taking cannonballs to the gut? Is she joining the circus?” Alas, this is not to be. Under the direction of some creepy looking bosses, Redd fights sea monsters looking to put a bite into urban areas. It’s pretty much Evangelion, but without the minimalist Angel designs or the cleverness.

[TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Webcomic/Redd) summary:

> *Redd* is a webcomic featuring the eponymous character Vicky Redd, an armless researcher who sports a set of floating waldos and works on technology involving translating neural signals to instruments. Outside of her research position, she also fights sea monsters (apparently a very common occurrence) and seems to be being groomed by a company named IBISEC to take down the extant superhero and supervillain community. In 2014, the comic went on hiatus and has since disappeared from the web, though it can still be found [through web archives](https://web.archive.org/web/20141203104800/http://www.bumrushcomics.com/?chapters=redd). In the meantime, creator Jack Cayless has moved on towards [developing a survival horror/comedy game](https://store.steampowered.com/app/870290/The_Miskatonic/), which features several Humanoid Abomination characters similar to the popular Redd character, Ezzie.

Cayless's other major strip was *[Chimneyspeak](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Webcomic/Chimneyspeak)* and indeed was considerably more saucy. It, too, has been removed from the web, but is available on [Lulu](http://www.lulu.com/us/en/shop/jack-cayless/chimneyspeak-1whitechapel/ebook/product-17349552.html) and [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00943EB22).